# Cant see Alert Box after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

```
function showAlert():void
{
    var alert:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:alert('Please enter your User name')");
    navigateToURL(alert, "");
}
```

I can't see the alert box (pop-up) after clicking button. What is the source of the problem? Even if I tried 3 different browser it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExternalInterface` is the standard way of communicating between AS3 and JS (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)):

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function showAlert() 
{
    // Check ExternalInterface is available
    if (ExternalInterface.available) 
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Please enter your User name");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but problem is still continue. Nothing happened

Comment: Have you set allowScriptAccess to true in your object embed tags in the HTML?

Comment: Yeah I everytime sign it true while publishing my object.

Comment: Actually, I think it should be set to 'always' - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1339254